# What is the best way to find the count of trailing spaces of string in C#?

Tags: c#

I have let's say millions of strings with or without trailing spaces. I want to count the number of trailing spaces in each string.

I am doing this for each string.

```
int count = input.Length - input.TrimEnd().Length;
```

But I think this is inefficient because I am creating an unnecessary string by using `TrimEnd()` method for each string.

I have thought of using another method to count the trailing spaces by traversing the string in the reverse direction for each character and check till the first nonspace character (increment the count by 1).

Is there any faster and efficient way to do this? strings are small but in millions.

Comment: `Reverse` and `TakeWhile` and `Count` are one option to consider. Will it be faster though? https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: If you already have "millions of strings", it'll be a little late to worry about creating even more of them. I mean, not useless, but almost certainly not the main problem. It is fairly simple to write a method that just reverse-iterates through the string the usual way without allocating anything.

Comment: You could use parallelization, if you have millions of strings. It won't make one operation faster, but all the operations together will become faster.

Comment: `strings are small but in millions.` If they are small, I'd do it the way you have it now. Its clean, easy to read and good enough. Allocating small strings likely isn't worth worrying about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I've done no profiling, and made it it in to an extension method:

```
void Main()
{
    string test = "StackOverflow     ";
    int count = test.WhiteSpaceAtEnd();
}

public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static int WhiteSpaceAtEnd(this string self)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int ix = self.Length - 1;
        while (ix >= 0 && char.IsWhiteSpace(self[ix--]))
            ++count;

        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd like to mention, when working with efficient string operations, [Span](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.asspan?view=netstandard-2.1#System_MemoryExtensions_AsSpan_System_String_) is worth a look

Comment: @kapsiR: Going through a `Span` is no more efficient than indexing the string directly. (A major design goal is also that it should not be *less* efficient, of course.) There may be ways to use `Span` to cut down on the creation of strings in the first place, but it's impossible to tell without additional context.

Comment: Probably would be spiffy to have performance results for a question about _"faster way"_.  Otherwise how do we know?  Then again question is off-topic

Comment: @MickyD Absolutely, I just knocked it up in LINQPad whilst on lunch, not really able to put together a proper Benchmark :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice You rock-star you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 possible solutions, one using a `for` loop and the other using Linq. These are both in the form of extension methods.

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static int CountTrailingSpaces(this string s) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = s.Length- 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i])) {
                count++;
            }
            else {
                return count;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
    public static int CountTrailingSpacesLinq(this string s) {
        return s.Reverse().TakeWhile(Char.IsWhiteSpace).Count();
    }
}
```

Then you can call these as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string s = "test  ";

    Console.WriteLine(s.CountTrailingSpaces());
    Console.WriteLine(s.CountTrailingSpacesLinq());
}
```

The output I receive using this test code is:

> 2
>
> 2

To add some quick performace metrics. My strong recomendation would be to use `CountTrailingSpaces`. As shown below this is significantly faster.

The total number of ticks taken using the `for` loop to do 1,000,000 operations on a string vs the `linq` method is significantly different.

For:  803529 ticks

Linq: 7171201 ticks

The performance testing code is shown below:

```
class Program {
    private static Random Random;
    private static Stopwatch Stopwatch;

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Random = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        decimal forLoop = 0;
        decimal linq = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            string s = RandomString(100);

            Stopwatch.Restart();
            s.CountTrailingSpaces();
            Stopwatch.Stop();

            forLoop += Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;

            Stopwatch.Restart();
            s.CountTrailingSpacesLinq();
            Stopwatch.Stop();

            linq += Stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"For:\t{forLoop}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Linq:\t{linq}");
    }
    private static string RandomString(int length) {
        const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789          ";
        return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
          .Select(s => s[Random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
}

public static class StringExtensions {
    public static int CountTrailingSpaces(this string s) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = s.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (Char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i])) {
                count++;
            }
            else {
                return count;
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
    public static int CountTrailingSpacesLinq(this string s) {
        return s.Reverse().TakeWhile(Char.IsWhiteSpace).Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to microbenchmark, you should probably use [tools that are designed to do it right](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/). Even so, benchmarking this is fairly pointless as there's little reason to assume the operation is a bottleneck -- when running on millions of strings, it's probably the reading and allocating of those millions of strings that is. If you really had cause to optimize the proverbial crap out of this, there are more advanced tricks to pull (like checking entire machine words of data rather than individual characters and/or specializing to spaces only).